# Set value of "column b" with "column a"

Tags: 2010, column, calendar, outlook, choice-field

I would venture to guess the answer to this is *no* but I am going to ask anyway...

Is there any way, without an event handler, to set "column b" equal to "column a" without changing the default value of "column b".

I am trying to set a "single line of text" column equal to the value of a "choice" dropdown column. In my situation I cannot use a calculated column.

**Full Explanation:**
In an Outlook 2010 calendar I can send values back and forth to SharePoint on a column named "Categories". This column will send data from SharePoint *to* Outlook no matter what type it is. However, Outlook appears to only send changes to SharePoint if the column is the type "single line of text". How can I set a column to the type "choice" and yet still accept changes from Outlook in SharePoint when the column must be a "single line of text"?

Answer (score 0):

It might involve a workflow on the SP list.

Make the WF trigger on change/create of the field and the n update a value in a dropdown based from your "Category" field.

If Category A change dropdown field to A
 Else if Category B change dropdown to B
[image: Pseudo WF markup]

and so on...
build more ifs and then populate your dropdown in SharePoint.